# building c++ config file parser using lex and yacc

Tags: c++, c, yacc, lex

I am trying to build config file parser (c++ application)from scratch using tools like lex and yacc. The parser will be able to parse files like

```
# Sub group example
petName = Tommy
Owner = {
   pet = "%petName%"
}
```

Is there any step by step guide/link to articles on how to achieve this using tools like lex and yacc? The idea is I will write a class say Config (c++) with methods like getConfig(string propName). If I invoke like config.getConfig(Owner.pet), it will return me Tommy.

Comment: You might want to consider using a JSON library which has a similar format to what you are showing, you will just need to adapt the format of the file a bit.

Comment: What David said. Or you might consider [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) instead of lex & yacc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Boost Property Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/property_tree.html)

It was designed for configuration files. It does reading, writing in the following formats:

- INI
- INFO
- XML
- JSON

Here is the five minute tutorial page which should give you a good idea:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html

Comment: To the downvoter: I know this doesn't answer the exact question. However, the OP left _plenty of room_ for interpretation. `using tools like...` is an open invitation, IYAM

Comment: a quick question is do they support syntax like pet = "%petName%" where petName is defined somewhere else?

Comment: I'd actually just code that up using [boost::spirit::qi::symbols](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/string/symbols.html), a regex replace with formatter, or manual traversal and simple string replaces. I don't think it is be good design to include 'magic' in your own config file reader. The good old UNIX mantra: use existing blocks that do _one thing_ well (no need to reinvent wheels because they're painted the wrong colour :)). Of course you could make a single function that does the magic 'combination' behind the scenes for _your_ application.